# how to show an image from link taken by database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm developing an asp.net web application using web forms with mysql database. In my application I have stored images in folder and links for that images are stored in the database
I want to display those images by taking those links from the database
I tried the following codes to show the image

home.aspx.cs

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
       profile_picture = (string)(Session["link"]); //link has been taken from db
    }
```

home.aspx

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="profile_picture" ImageUrl="Label"></asp:Image>
```

Error is =>Error    4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'
how to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
profile_picture.ImageUrl = (string)(Session["link"]);
```

That should help. not sure if ImageUrl is the correct property but look at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image which is what "profile_picture" is typeOf and see what property the image link should be set to.